# Random Selenium webdriver passing failing on Mozilla

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, junit4, assertions

I'm writing test scripts for a website written in Angular 2. I'm using Selenium 2.53.1 and Mozilla 45.0, Junit 4.12

I have the same tests passing and then again the same tests not passing when executing not even 20 minutes later. I have all my functions saved in a superclass and the test cases in classes that inherits from it.

This is the Fail Trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: priceSheet
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'VP1240940', ip: '10.12.50.247', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 5e182ec9-8d39-499e-b05f-fc66f054f140
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:261)
    at lieuxBatimentsMontreal.test.WebElements.confirmTarifsChange(WebElements.java:412)
    at lieuxBatimentsMontreal.test.ModifierUnBatiment.ModifierLeTarif(ModifierUnBatiment.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"priceSheet"}
Command duration or timeout: 15.08 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'VP1240940', ip: '10.12.50.247', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 5e182ec9-8d39-499e-b05f-fc66f054f140
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=priceSheet}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:899)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$0(ExpectedConditions.java:897)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:653)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"priceSheet"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'VP1240940', ip: '10.12.50.247', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/xtoumni/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4418321286959635118webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/xtoumni/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4418321286959635118webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:625)
```

The ID is there. The same test cases passed few minutes earlier...

Please let me know if anyone have had this problem before. It needs to be super stable as these tests will be included in the Jenkins flow. The deployment of new versions will depend on my tests.

Comment: isn't the exception clear enough ? Probably, the element is hidden, or is generated by JavaScript

Comment: 1) @ChandlerBing it's not a permanent fail. As i mentioned, it passes and fails randomly when no code has changed. 
Angular  is all based on Javascript yes. But does that mean that Selenium can not be reliable to test Angular websites?

Comment: @NickThomas Selenium doesn't give you javascript generated html. If your website consists on mostly that, you would have problems.

Comment: Again, my website is made with Angular 2. Are we saying that Selenium can not be depended upon with Angular JS, 2 and 4 websites?

Comment: You may be somewhere close. For Angularjs, Jasmine & Protector combination suits better. Thanks

Comment: Wont we have a call back problem with Protractor? 
All the functions are promises...

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can't tell when all the JavaScript has finished loading the DOM.  So every selenium programmer needs a strategy for determining when it is safe to continue.  For angular, I do two things:

A. Wait for Browser ReadyState=complete.

```
public void waitForBrowserReadystateComplete(WebDriver webDriver) {
    for (int a=0; a<20; a++) {
        JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
        if (javascriptExecutor.executeScript("return document.readyState")
                .toString().equals("complete")) {
            break;
        }
        sleepResponsibly(500);
    }
}

public void sleepResponsibly(int timeMillisecond){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(timeMillisecond);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

B. Wait for the angular to finish loading the DOM

```
public boolean waitForAngularToLoad(WebDriver driver, int timeout) {
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout, 500L);
    return wait.until(angularHasFinishedProcessing());
}


public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> angularHasFinishedProcessing() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            String hasAngularFinishedScript = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];\n" +
                    "var el = document.querySelector('html');\n" +
                    "if (!window.angular) {\n" +
                    "    callback('false')\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "if (angular.getTestability) {\n" +
                    "    angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(function(){callback('true')});\n" +
                    "} else {\n" +
                    "    if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {\n" +
                    "        callback('false')\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "    var browser = angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser');\n" +
                    "    browser.notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(function(){callback('true')});\n" +
                    "}";

            JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            String isProcessingFinished = javascriptExecutor.executeAsyncScript(hasAngularFinishedScript).toString();

            return Boolean.valueOf(isProcessingFinished);
        }
    };
}
```

In your specific case, I would code the following:

```
WebDriverWait wait_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
WebElement anElement = wait_element.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("priceSheet")));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(anElement).click().build().perform();
```

Handles many special cases (e.g. scrolling) but not all (e.g. loading spinner overlying anElement and absorbing the click).  But it is more surefire than a simple click.

Comment: I have other methods for waiting for the loading spinner to become invisible but they depend on the implementation and are not generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String confirmTarifsChange(){
    String tarifs;
    WebDriverWait wait_element = new WebDriverWait(driver1, 40);
    WebElement anElement = wait_element.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("priceSheet")));
    tarifs = anElement.getText();
    return tarifs;

}
```

I used this piece of code but still isn't working in a stable manner. I still have some problems. 
I oculdn't use the Action because this function needs to return a string using normally getText() but it's not available in the Action librairie.

@MikeJRamsey56